# pluralize and decapitalize nouns in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capitalization, pluralize

I am implementing a view count feature for particular web pages in Ruby on Rails. I use haml lists to achieve my end. (The JavaScript library takes the list and render it as dropdowns.)

Here is the code snippet:

```
%li.action
  = link_to t(question.views_count.to_s + ' views')
```

My problem here is that the V in views is capitalized in the output and view is pluralized even for 0 and 1 number of views. Is there any way I can deal with these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong, you should be letting the I18N system (i.e. the `t` method) deal with the pluralization on its own. Proper plural handling is horribly complicated, don't try to do it yourself with string manipulation. You're using the `t` method but it can do a lot more for you.

From the [I18N Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization):

> The `:count` interpolation variable has a special role in that it both is interpolated to the translation and used to pick a pluralization from the translations according to the pluralization rules defined by CLDR:
>
> ```
> I18n.backend.store_translations :en, :inbox => {
>   :one => '1 message',
>   :other => '%{count} messages'
> }
>
> I18n.translate :inbox, :count => 2
> # => '2 messages'
> ```

So assuming you have your message database properly set up, then you would do something like this:

```
t(:views, :count => question.views_count)
```

And your English translation file would have something like this:

```
views:
  one: "1 view"
  other: "%{count} views"
```

Answer (score 1):

see this link for pluralize
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize

try in your `console`, `for example`

```
1.9.3p125 :028 > pluralize(2, 'View')
 => "2 Views"
```

**Update**

try in your console and use **[capitalize](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-capitalize)**

```
"view".capitalize
```

Comment: Thanks. Can anyone try to suggest why I am getting a capital v even though I have used a small v in the string?